# async and await with try except

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, discord.py

I'm learning async in python doing a simple music bot for discord.
I am encountering several problems, for example when I do operations like skip or similar, apparently my ctx becomes None and I get an error in the console, however the bot not only does not stop for the error but does what it should.
So I don't understand why it becomes None and why if I try to manage it with a try except or if I remove the await from the stop, the skip command no longer does what it should and skips 2 songs instead of just one.
I put some prints to understand the flow and actually if the stop's await is not taken, because I remove it or because the try except, then the code once arrived at the source, restarts, doing 2 skip instead of 1. Why? How do I prevent the code from being repeated twice and without errors in the console?

I think the problem is that stop is not awaitable, because it returns None.
But if this is the problem, why if I remove the await it skips 2 song instead of one? I'm really going crazy

play func:

```
    async def real_play(self, ctx, vc, url):
        if ctx != None and ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            await ctx.voice_client.stop()
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            if self.queue[0] == [0, 0, 0]:
                self.queue.pop(0)
            elif len(self.queue) > 0:
                self.currentsonginfo = self.queue.pop(0)
                with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
                    ydl.cache.remove()
                    info = ydl.extract_info(self.currentsonginfo[0], download=False)
                processed_url_song = info['formats'][0]['url']
                source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(processed_url_song, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
                await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
                self.playing = True
                vc.play(source, after=lambda e: asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.real_play(ctx, vc, processed_url_song), self.client.loop))
                await self.info(ctx)
        else:
            self.playing = False
            await self.timer(ctx)
```

skip func:

```
@commands.command()
    async def skip(self, ctx):
        if len(self.queue) > 0:
            next_song_url = self.queue[0][0]
            await ctx.send("⏩ Song Skipped", delete_after=self.expiretimemsg)
            await self.real_play(ctx, ctx.voice_client, next_song_url)
```

Comment: Could you provide the whole error message?

Comment: I don't know how but I solved that problem, however the await problem repeating the function to me persists and it's my main problem!

Comment: Can I still have the error message?

Comment: sure, I have not the entire error but there is it:
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression

Comment: Look at the error message, which line of code is setting it off?

Comment: await ctx.voice_client.stop() this is the line that were triggering the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240542/discussion-between-c-gian-and-epicefeathers).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, basically `ctx.voice_client.stop()` stop the CURRENT song being played, so if you recall the play func like I was doing, the after lambda and this play func recall will collide, like you are recalling the play func 2 times.
To implement a skip, it is enough to use the after lambda and then in the skip func saying `ctx.voice_client.stop()`, no more needed, hope this will help anybody.